# Failed to create a default .NET runtime which would have been "netfx" on this system

Tags: .net, runtime, python.net

I am trying run a python script that is importing clr as below:

`import clr`

But i am getting the following error while executing the python scripts:

> Failed to create a default .NET runtime which would have been "netfx" on this system. Either install a compatible runtime or configure explicitly via 'set_runtime' or the 'PYTHONNET_*' environment variables (see set_runtime_from_env)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this description found [on github](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet#net-core).

```py
from pythonnet import load
load('coreclr')
import clr
```

I don't really know what caused the problem in my case, as it ran without problems before (maybe python/pythonnet update?). But it seems that the problem is that the wrong .NET installation is loaded.